# how to show second screen of the array when presentController(withNames:contexts:) is executed

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, watchkit, wkinterfacecontroller

```
presentController(withNames:["ScreenOne", "ScreenTwo", "ScreenThree"], contexts:nil)
```

when the above line is executed, the `ScreenOne` screen shows up as below:

[first page in the array is highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUdHC.png)

how would I go about getting the second page to show up when the above line is executed. i.e. `ScreenTwo`

[I want second page to show up in the array like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDPO6.png)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want the array to create a paginator controller with the items? Are the items nibs?

Comment: @Sirens I'm currently presented with `ScreenOne` with pagination and they are ordered as per the array. No issues with order. I need the `ScreenTwo` to show up with option to either swipe left to see `ScreenThree` or an option to swipe right to see `ScreenOne`

Comment: Any news on that? Have you managed to succeed?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display another page, you'll need to insert, in the `awake` method of the chosen controller a call to `becomeCurrentPage()`.

```
override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    // Do your stuff with the context and determine if it is the controller to display

    if mustBeDisplayed {
        becomeCurrentPage()
    }
}
```